# How to implement Global Styles in NextJS with SCSS?

Tags: next.js

I want to use Global Styles in my NextJS Application. According to the Documentation, the way I wrote my code should be correct. But it's not getting applied to.

- I am using SCSS as my styling language, and TSX for my nextjs files.
- My scoped styles are getting applied.

### My Code

`_App.tsx`

```
import "../components/SCSS/variables/AllVariables.global.scss";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

`AllVariables.global.scss`

```
@use "./breakpoints" as *;
@use "./changeable-settings" as *;
@use "./fixed-settings-color" as *;
@use "./fixed-settings-font" as *;
@use "./fixed-settings-grid" as *;
@use "./headings" as *;
@use "./zindex" as *;
```

Two examples from the files that are being imported into `AllVariables.global.scss`:

```
$sm: 600px; // tablet
$md: 900px; // laptop
$lg: 1200px; // desktop
$xl: 1500px; // large desktop
$xxl: 3000px; // 4K desktop
```

```
:root {
  /* [Font Settings] */
  --xs-font-size: 0.6rem;
  --sm-font-size: 0.8rem;
  --reg-font-size: 1rem;
  --md-font-size: 1.2rem;
  --lg-font-size: 1.4rem;
  --xl-font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

I followed the Instruction from the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-support), where it states that SCSS is being handled the same as CSS. I did install `sass`, as it was mentioned. And [here](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/12/09/global-styles-in-next.js/) it is also explained, the same way, how to import global styles, and [here as well](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17089).

In these examples, they use CSS and JS, and again, I use SCSS and TSX.

In my opinion, it *should* work, but obviously, it doesn't. Something is wrong, and I can't find any official source on how to achieve global styles with SCSS.

Comment: Have you installed node-sass ?

Comment: @Freestyle09 node-sass is deprecated. I installed `sass`, as I mentioned in the post. And I also said my scoped styles work, the only problem I have are my global styles.

Comment: Yeah I see it now, Try to implement background-color for body element to check that your import is properly written

Comment: This is the question I am asking. My global style does *not* work, and I am here asking what the solution to my problem is. Whatever I have in my global style is not being applied.

Comment: Have you tried that? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#customizing-sass-options

Comment: That's for customising my SCSS more, which I didn't have the need for. In their example they use the path feature, so I don't need to use long relative paths for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228993/discussion-between-mahnenwolf-and-freestyle09).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was trying to find a solution to this for a few hours now. But I kept using the wrong keywords.

The problem was with TypeScript and App.

> If your app is running and you just added a custom App, you'll need to restart the development server. Only required if pages/_app.js didn't exist before.

And this: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#custom-app

Comment: Good job ;) Glad you find the answer